# How to save contact info from vCard into iPhone's Contacts App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, vcf-vcard

In my iPhone app, I want to save the vCards into my iPhone's Contacts when I click onto the vCard which I have.

How can I do that?

I have seen an app on app store which does this:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/read-vcard/id402216831?mt=8

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if its possible just to send it to a Gmail account and import it that way?  Oh you'll probably get a better answer from the guys over at http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Yzmir Ramirez: This is a question from programming point of view not the iPhone (hardware) functionality point of view. So I think this is proper question of stackoverflow. I want to do this programmatically through my application.

Comment: My bad.  I wish I could help.  The vCard format isn't that tough to parse, but I too would like to know if there's something built-in to solve this programatically.

Comment: @ParthBhatt: I dont know about vCard, but i can help you to insert information in iPhone's contacts. If you need let me know.

Comment: Thankfully, iOS 7 *finally* allows direct importing of vCards into Contacts.

Comment: @Have you written code to handle if there are duplicates of the vCard in the device already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is the code for adding user information in `iPhone's Contact`.

As I told you that i dont know anything about the `vCard`, but this code [posted by malinois in their answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5378410/19679) might be of use:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate(); // create address book record 
ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate(); // create a person  

NSString *phone = @"0123456789"; // the phone number to add  

//Phone number is a list of phone number, so create a multivalue  
ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty); 
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue ,phone,kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);

ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"FirstName" , nil); // first name of the new person 
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty, @"LastName", nil); // his last name 
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMultiValue, &anError); // set the phone number property 
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, person, nil); //add the new person to the record

ABRecordRef group = ABGroupCreate(); //create a group 
ABRecordSetValue(group, kABGroupNameProperty,@"My Group", &error); // set group's name 
ABGroupAddMember(group, person, &error); // add the person to the group         
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, group, &error); // add the group   

ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, nil); //save the record  

CFRelease(person); // relase the ABRecordRef  variable
```

Comment: Thanks Devang..!! I will look at it.. and I will get back to you soon.. :)

Answer (score 5):

New Contacts Framework introduced with iOS9, saving vCard data into iPhone's contacts is much easier and simpler with Swift4.

```
import Contacts

    func saveVCardContacts (vCard : Data) { // assuming you have alreade permission to acces contacts

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {

        let contactStore = CNContactStore()

        do {

            let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest() // create saveRequests

            let contacts = try CNContactVCardSerialization.contacts(with: vCard) // get contacts array from vCard

            for person in contacts{

                saveRequest.add(person as! CNMutableContact, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil) // add contacts to saveRequest

            }

            try contactStore.execute(saveRequest) // save to contacts

        } catch  {

            print("Unable to show the new contact") // something went wrong

        }

    }else{

        print("CNContact not supported.") //

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the value addition to this post..!!

Comment: @yvzzztrk, only  for 9.0? i am new to ios app development, but i am developing from ios 8.0. What is 8.0 equivalent for CNContact?

Comment: hi @alex, you can use **ABAddressBoook** , look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837828/unable-to-create-a-person-using-vcard-representation/33274235#33274235)

Comment: @yvzzztrk i follow your link and got it to work with your answer. Another question do you have a link how to first show a popup with vcard fields before saving?

Comment: @alex, look at [AddressBookUI](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Framework/index.html) framework, and [ABUnknownPersonViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABUnknownPersonViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/ABUnknownPersonViewController)

Comment: @yvzzztrk thank you! last question when i create it for ios 8 will it work in ios 9 as well?

Comment: @alex, yes of course,but I suggest you to use **CNContact** framework for iOS 9 with **if #available(iOS 9.0, *) { /*code*/ }** as in the my answer

Comment: can you do this also in objective-c  using CNContact

Comment: `saveRequest.add(person as! CNMutableContact, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)` crashes for me. It says that it "could not cast value of type 'CNContact' (0x1142c85f8) to 'CNMutableContact' (0x1142c7568)". Swift 3, iOS 9.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you for coding, but I have found the common format of vCard in [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622636/iphone-can-not-read-company-name-from-qr-code). You can try to achieve your task using this format. The left side values are always static. Hope if you can use that way.

For just reference, i found googling... (support for all 3 mobile platforms)

http://learnyii.blogspot.com/2011/04/vcard-qr-code-iphone-android-blackberry.html

Answer (score 1):

```
func saveContactsfromVCard(vCard : Data)
    {            
            let contactStore = CNContactStore()

            do {

                let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest() // create saveRequests

                let fetchedContacts = try CNContactVCardSerialization.contacts(with: vCard)

                for person in fetchedContacts{

                   let mutableContact = person.mutableCopy() as! CNMutableContact

                    saveRequest.add(mutableContact, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)    
                   // saveRequest.add(person, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil) // add contacts to saveRequest

                }

                try contactStore.execute(saveRequest) // save to contacts

                let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "Successful", message: "Contacts Added Successfully!", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

                alert1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler:
                    {(alertAction) in
                }))
                self.present(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)


            } catch  {

                print("Unable to show the new contact")
        }else{

            print("Contacts not added")

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ABMutableMultiValueRef date = ABRecordCopyValue(newPerson, kABPersonDateProperty);
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(date, dateTextField.text, kABPersonAnniversaryLabel, NULL);            
    ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonDateProperty, date,nil);
```