# Read/Parse Data from vCard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, vcf-vcard

Is there any framework/library available in iOS SDK to read/parse data in vCard format?
I am receiving data in a vcard format in a NSString and I have to parse it.
Googled a lot, but couldn't find solution yet.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:LastName;FirstName;MiddleName;Prefix;Sufix
ADR;TYPE=HOME: postbox;street2;street1;city;state;zip;country
BDAY:2010-08-19
END:VCARD
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did found some solutions for you...

Have a look at the following links...

**1)** Want ready made sample code==>[Click here](http://altoshstock.blogspot.in/2010/11/iphone-os-generate-vcard.html)

**2)** Writing to Vcard==>[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132326/how-to-save-contact-info-from-vcard-into-iphones-contacts-app)

Code Relevent to you:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate(); // create address book record 
ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate(); // create a person  

NSString *phone = @"0123456789"; // the phone number to add  

//Phone number is a list of phone number, so create a multivalue  
ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty); 
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue ,phone,kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);

ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"FirstName" , nil); // first name of the new person 
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty, @"LastName", nil); // his last name 
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMultiValue, &anError); // set the phone number property 
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, person, nil); //add the new person to the record

ABRecordRef group = ABGroupCreate(); //create a group 
ABRecordSetValue(group, kABGroupNameProperty,@"My Group", &error); // set group's name 
ABGroupAddMember(group, person, &error); // add the person to the group         
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, group, &error); // add the group   

ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, nil); //save the record  

CFRelease(person); // relase the ABRecordRef  variable
```

**3)** Importing vCard sample code==>[Click here](https://github.com/aussiegeek/AddressBookVcardImport)

**4)** For creating custom parser ==> [Click here](http://softsolutions.blog.com/2011/07/21/vcard-version-2-1-parser/)

Comment: @Puneed Kamath
Thanks a lot the detailed response and ref codes.
I have used vCardImporter. The issue is I dont want to save anything in my Contacts App using Address Book. I just want to parse and get desired values like this.

vCard.FName // will return First Name
vCard.Phone // will return me Phone.

do u have idea how can i do it ?

Comment: @TaimurAjmal..wish i would have had my mac with me now...i could have wrote code for you..but partially i can guide you...

check it==>http://softsolutions.blog.com/2011/07/21/vcard-version-2-1-parser/

Comment: if([[abc objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@”WORK”])
{

}

Answer (score 4):

OS X v10.11 and iOS 9 introduces [CNContactVCardSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContactVCardSerialization_Class/index.html) which makes parsing a VCard a breeze.

Comment: heads up! iOs does not support unicode out of the box. We will need to modify the qrcode in order to accept unicode characters. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287505/cncontact-encoding-of-properties