# How to get Mobile Number from vCard String Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, vcf-vcard

I am working on Action Extension Objective C. I have successfully created Extension for share recent contact in my Extension. In that I am getting v Card String. How can I get Mobile Number from v Card String. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `contactsWithData:error:` method of `CNContactVCardSerialization`?

Comment: Can you please provide some code samples

Comment: @PareshVasoya The Apple documentation is usually very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Using `contactsWithData:error:` class method of `CNContactVCardSerialization`, you can retrieve info from a vCard.
It's from `Contacts.framework`, available since iOS9.
For earlier version, you can use `AddressBook.framework`. You can read info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976481/read-parse-data-from-vcard).

```
    NSError *errorVCF;
    NSArray  *allContacts = [CNContactVCardSerialization contactsWithData:[contactStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] error:&errorVCF];
    if (!errorVCF)
    {
        NSMutableString *results = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
       //NSLog(@"AllContacts: %@", allContacts);
        for (CNContact *aContact in allContacts)
        {
            NSArray *phonesNumbers = [aContact phoneNumbers];
            for (CNLabeledValue *aValue in phonesNumbers)
            {
                CNPhoneNumber *phoneNumber = [aValue value];
                [results appendFormat:@"%@ %@\n", [aValue label], [phoneNumber stringValue]];
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"Final: %@", results);
    }
```