# IPhone AddressBook method to return or create a ABRecord

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, addressbook

I'm having real trouble with the AddressBook and memory.  I want it to return a record (either the existing one or a new one) that I can save a contact into.  There is a lot wrong with this function according to the build and analyze tool.  I have read the documentation and re-written this a bunch of times but I cant seem to get it right.

Whats the correct way to write this method? / What am I doing wrong?

```
//Searches Groups by name for matches and returns the attached record
- (ABRecordRef)getGroup
{   
    ABRecordRef response;

NSArray *groups = (NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups(addressBook);

for (id group in groups)
{
    NSString *currentGroup = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(group, kABGroupNameProperty);
    if ([currentGroup isEqualToString:GroupName])
    {
        response = group;
        CFRelease(currentGroup); //??
        break;
    }
    CFRelease(currentGroup); //?
}

[groups release];

if (response == NULL)
{
    response = ABGroupCreate();
    ABRecordSetValue(response, kABGroupNameProperty, GroupName, &error);
    ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, response, &error);
    ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);
}
return response;
```

}

Comment: Not going to answer since I don't know the AB API very well, but at the very least you need to autorelease response, since it's returned by a call that contains "create"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its easier and more reliable to just get the Record ID.
If found this on an unrelated post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8249975/874927

```
- (BOOL)checkIfGroupExists
{   
    BOOL hasGroup = NO;

    CFIndex groupCount = ABAddressBookGetGroupCount(addressBook);
    CFArrayRef groups = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups(addressBook);

    for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++)
    {
        ABRecordRef currentGroup = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(groups, i);
        NSString *currentGroupName = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(currentGroup);

        if ([currentGroupName isEqualToString:GroupName])
        {
            hasGroup = YES;
            groupRecordId = ABRecordGetRecordID(currentGroup);
        }
        CFRelease(currentGroupName);
    }

    if (hasGroup == NO)
    {
        [self createNewGroup];
    }

    CFRelease(groups);
    return hasGroup;
}
```