# Adding phone contact programatically in ios sdk

Tags: ios, contacts

I know there is way that, a user can add a phone contact in ios sdk as referenced in the link [How to create contacts in address book in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377441/how-to-create-contacts-in-address-book-in-iphone-sdk)

At present, whether is this allowed by the Apple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is allowed by the Apple.