# How do i create a contact in Address Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook

I have code to add a contact to iOS 6 address book. The code looks similar to the answers on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377441/how-to-create-contacts-in-address-book-in-iphone-sdk). The problem is that all the addresses for the contact all come out in the US format.

[image]

If i go and create a contact in the address book manually (for country UK), here is what the format looks like.

[image]

Is there any thing I am missing? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting `kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey` ?

I think you have set only `kABPersonAddressCountryKey`

For more about these constant [read docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210-CH991-SW26)

Comment: Thanks dude. I had tried this before. But it seems i was giving it the incorrect country code value. I've now started used codes from here _> http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/country_names_and_code_elements.htm  thanks, works!