# Swift: Set Address Property of ABRecord

Tags: ios, swift, abaddressbook, abrecord, abmultivalue

I took a look at the SE question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377441/how-to-create-contacts-in-address-book-in-iphone-sdk) [Avinash's answer] and the Apple resource [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone.pdf) [bottom of page 18 and top of page 19] in my attempt to set an address for an `ABRecord`. I did my best to translate them from Objective-C, but apparently I made an mistake somewhere since on the line `let dict = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, keys, values, 5, &kCFCopyStringDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks)` I get the error `Cannot assign to immutable value of type 'CFDictionaryValueCallBacks'`.

Here's my code:

```
    let information: ABRecord = ABPersonCreate().takeRetainedValue()

    let address: ABMutableMultiValueRef = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(ABPropertyType(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType)).takeUnretainedValue()

    var keys = [CFStringRef]()
    var values = [CFStringRef]()

    keys.append(kABPersonAddressStreetKey)
    keys.append(kABPersonAddressCityKey)
    keys.append(kABPersonAddressStateKey)
    keys.append(kABPersonAddressZIPKey)
    keys.append(kABPersonAddressCountryKey)
    keys.append(kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey)

    Note: country code left out

    values.append(s["kABPersonAddressStreetKey"]!! as NSString)
    values.append(s["kABPersonAddressCityKey"]!! as NSString)
    values.append(s["kABPersonAddressStateKey"]!! as NSString)
    values.append(s["kABPersonAddressZIPKey"]!! as NSString)
    values.append(s["kABPersonAddressCountryKey"]!! as NSString)
    values.append(s["kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey"]!! as NSString)

    let dict = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, keys, values, 5, &kCFCopyStringDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks)

    let scanned = ABUnknownPersonViewController()

    let identifier = ABMultiValueIdentifier()

    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(address, dict, kABHomeLabel, &identifier)

    ABRecordSetValue(information, kABPersonAddressProperty, address, nil)
```

Comment: You will find it a lot easier to work in the NSDictionary world instead of the CFDictionary world. There is absolutely no need for anything but NSDictionary here. Just form the dictionary in normal Swift.

Comment: @matt Hi, thanks for the tip. I tried `let dict: NSDictionary = [kABPersonAddressStreetKey : s["kABPersonAddressStreetKey"]!! as NSString,...`, but got an error saying that there was no overload for subscript which accepts the following arguments. Could you or anyone else possibly provide a little sample code as to how to implement your suggestion?

Comment: What is `s`? It looks like it is already the dictionary you want.

Comment: @matt It's a regular (not NS) dictionary of type [String : String?], which holds a lot more information besides the address. Also, the keys are of type String, and not ABProperty, so I'm not sure if it would work unmodified

Comment: Okay, but let me get this straight. You are having trouble forming the dictionary based on `s`. You want someone to help you fix that trouble so your code will compile. But you are not willing to show what `s` actually is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a much more concise way to do this, but here's the solution I've come up with.

```
 var addressComponents = [String : String]()

    if let value = s["kABPersonAddressStreetKey"] {
        addressComponents[kABPersonAddressStreetKey as String] =  value
    }

    if let value = s["kABPersonAddressCityKey"] {
        addressComponents[kABPersonAddressCityKey as String] = value
    }

    if let value = s["kABPersonAddressStateKey"] {
        addressComponents[kABPersonAddressStateKey as String] = value
    }

    if let value = s["kABPersonAddressZIPKey"] {
        addressComponents[kABPersonAddressZIPKey as String] = value
    }

    if let value = s["kABPersonAddressCountryKey"] {
        addressComponents[kABPersonAddressCountryKey as String] = value
    }

    if let value = s["kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey"] {
        addressComponents[kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey as String] = value
    }

    let address: ABMutableMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(ABPropertyType(kABMultiStringPropertyType)).takeRetainedValue()
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(address, addressComponents, kABHomeLabel, nil)
    ABRecordSetValue(information, kABPersonAddressProperty, address, nil)
```